# Anchor constraint in GridBagLayout not working

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GBLClumpingExample extends JFrame{

    GBLClumpingExample(){
        GridBagLayout g = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gv = new GridBagConstraints();

        GridBagLayout b = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(720,720);
        setLayout(g);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(b);
        gv.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(p,gv);
        
        Label l1 = new Label("Label 1");
        Label l2 = new Label("Label 2");
        Label l3 = new Label("Label 3");
        Label l4 = new Label("Label 4");
        Label l5 = new Label("Label 5");
        
        gc.weightx =1.0;
        gc.weighty = 1.0;
        gc.gridx= 1;
        gc.gridy= 1;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gc.gridx= -1;
        gc.gridy= 0;
        p.add(l1,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        p.add(l2,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        p.add(l3,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        p.add(l4,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        p.add(l5,gc);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GBLClumpingExample e = new GBLClumpingExample();
    }
}
```

I was trying to use `GridBagLayout` but maybe it is not working correctly.

This is my code I don't know what is wrong but anchor constraints of `GridBagConstraints` are not working, they are all just clump together.

Comment: `setVisible(true); setSize(720,720);` This is wrong. It should be `pack(); setVisible(true);` after **all** components are added. I usually put 'set visible' at the end of the constructor. And `720,720` is no better than a guess.

Comment: `anchor` will constrain the component to that position within the cell, but the cell will dealt to the preferred size of the component, so you probably are not "seeing" the result - since the `JPanel` won't expand to fill the frame

Comment: BTW 1) give examples a [better name than `example`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5dGq.png). I have exactly one package for all short codes like this, and every man and his dog wants to call there example code `example`. Make it something more specific like `GBLClumpingExample`. 2) And while offering tips: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. ..

Comment: .. 3) `Label l1 = new Label("Label 1");` should be `JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Label 1");` (etcetera for the others) - don't mix Swing and AWT components.

Comment: There are only three useful anchor GridBagConstraints;  GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, and GridBagConstraints.LINE_END.  You have to use the gridx and gridy parameters to position Swing components on the page.  Also, organize your code so that you group the method calls for each Swing component.  It makes it much easier for people to understand your code.  Here's Oracle's tutorial, How to use the GridBag Layout.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: Because I'm bored and wanted to try the code, I decided to implement suggestions (1) & (2) in my comments, and edited to add that code. Now it will be easier for others to work with it. Now I'll have a closer look at it.

Comment: As an aside.. `gc.gridx= -1;` What effect did you **expect** that to have? (Those constraints start from 0 and the end effect of -1 is .. undefined.)

Comment: Now I look at the problem more closely, I'll add another point: 4) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson `-1` for `gridx` is identical to [`GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE) which means placing the added component to the right of the previously added component. It’s even the default. Of course, it would be better to use the named constant to avoid such confusion.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc how do you come to the conclusion that “there are only three useful anchor”? The page you’ve linked already names nine but also mentions that the compass style constants are still valid. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#anchor) mentions even more, as the tutorial you’ve linked hasn’t been updated to mention the newer baseline anchors. Makes 27 valid anchor values, if I counted correctly…

Comment: @MadProgrammer you nailed it, the panel does not get resized, as it has been added with a constraints that was setup with `gv.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;`, but `gv.weightx` and `gv.weighty` were not set to nonzero values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding you components to a panel `p` which you are then adding to the frame (to its content pane) using `add(p,gv);`. The constraints in `gv` have been initialized with `gv.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;`, but its `weightx` and `weighty` are left at their initial zero. As a result, this panel will stay at its preferred size and not receive additional space, so it has no additional space to distribute to its own content.

Since all labels have the same size, their anchors have no effect when there is no additional space.

When you change the line

```
gv.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

to

```
gv.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gv.weightx = 1;
gv.weighty = 1;
```

you will see the effect of the anchors. Alternatively, you can get rid of the additional panel. There are other redundant operations too. You can simplify your code to:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GBAnchorExample extends JFrame{
    GBAnchorExample() {
        Container c = super.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.weightx = gc.weighty = 1.0;

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Label 3");
        JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Label 4");
        JLabel l5 = new JLabel("Label 5");

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        c.add(l1,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        c.add(l2,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.add(l3,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.add(l4,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.add(l5,gc);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GBAnchorExample e = new GBAnchorExample();
        e.setSize(720,720);
        e.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

To visualize the actual effect of the anchor you may change the `main` method to

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    GBAnchorExample e = new GBAnchorExample();
    Component grid = new JComponent() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
            for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                int x = (int)(w/5.0*i);
                g.drawLine(x, 0, x, h);
            }
        }
    };
    e.setGlassPane(grid);
    grid.setVisible(true);
    e.setSize(720,720);
    e.setVisible(true);
}
```

This will paint a green grid to show the logical cells containing the labels, so it becomes apparent how the anchors affect the labels’ positions within their cells.

Answer (score 0):

**If** I understand the intent of this layout correctly (I'm not *sure* I do) then this might be done using a `BorderLayout`.

[image]

Here it is with more width and height:

[image]

The titled borders are only there to provide a quick visual reference to the constraint used to place the component. The  `(spacer)` is only added to the 3 labels in the center row to allow the full `TitledBorder` to appear!

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class BLNotClumpingExample {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    BLNotClumpingExample() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));
        
        ui.add(getLabel("Label 1", "PAGE_START"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        ui.add(getLabel("Label 2", "PAGE_END"), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        ui.add(getLabel("Label 3 (spacer)", "LINE_END"), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        ui.add(getLabel("Label 4 (spacer)", "LINE_START"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        ui.add(getLabel("Label 5 (spacer)", "CENTER"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    
    private JLabel getLabel(String text, String constraint) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        l.setBorder(new TitledBorder(constraint));
        return l;
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            BLNotClumpingExample o = new BLNotClumpingExample();
            
            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            
            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
            
            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```